# Cannot get the input class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

When clicking "Reset To Default Settings" Button in my form, i want to clear to the default colors in my 4 colorpickers. They all have input type text fields with `anyicon-form-colorpicker` class. All i do is to find the `<a>` tag and clear his `style` tag with `.css()` function. The problem is that the third element which is is the image below is not being resetted and i don't know why. Here's my jQuery:

```
 $(document).on( 'click', '.anyicon-reset-button', function() {
     var inputs = $('#anyicon-live-style-form .anyicon-form-field');
     $.each(inputs, function(i, input){
         var split = $(input).attr('name').split('_')[1];
         $(input).val(default_values[split]);
         if ($(input).hasClass('anyicon-form-colorpicker')) {
             $(input).parent('.wp-picker-input-wrap').siblings('.wp-color-result').css('background-color', default_values[split]);
         }
     });
 });
```

And the DOM structure:
[image]

I'm 101% sure that all of the 4 elements have the class needed.

Comment: Probably not related,but css class names are not allowed to contain underscores.

Comment: so, are you saying that the  `inputs` variable is empty? without much info of the html, can't give much idea. Where is this `anyicon-live-style-form`?

Comment: the inputs variable is the the variable with all input fields data, and it's not empty. anyicon-live-style-form is  id of the form

Comment: For what `default_values` is?

Comment: That's the default color value, which is correct

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you got `#anyicon-live-style-form` from but I can't see it in the DOM Structure you posted. Have you tried

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.anyicon-reset-button', function() {
   var inputs = $('#anyicon_anycolor .anyicon-form-field');
   ...
 });
```

Comment: Is there any output in your console?

Comment: Mmm no. Don't know what's happening here

Comment: Please, post your related HTML so we could try to simulate the problem

Comment: Let's continue the discussion into the chat ?

Comment: Sure! Go ahead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154417/discussion-between-rumen-and-kbj).